# Телеграмм бот. Не приходит результат выполнения функции

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot

При нажатии кнопки "Повторы" должен приходить результат выполнения функции. Функция у меня - это sql запрос. В терминале ответ приходит. Не понимаю как мне осуществить это. Бот присылает ошибку, что сообщение пустое. И как я понимаю, ошибка в том, что сначала должна выполниться функция, но я не понимаю как это реализовать

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text.strip() == 'Повторы':
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, repetition())
```

Функция

```
def repetition():
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect (username, password, HOST+":"+PORT+"/"+SERVICE_NAME)

    print('Connecting!')
    cursor = conn.cursor() 

    sql = q1

    cursor.execute(sql) 
    alldata = cursor.fetchall()
        
    for i in alldata:
        print(i[0])
    cursor.close() 
    conn.close()
```

Comment: 1) `message.text.strip() == 'Повторы'` уверены, что код вызывается и условие выполняется? 2) `repetition()` мб проблема в функции, нужно ее показать, добавив в вопрос код

Comment: @gil9red Да, уверен, потому что при нажатии кнопки в боте, приходит результат выполнения функции в VSC(выходные данные), где запущен бот

Comment: @Karlail так вы же просто принтите результат, а не возвращаете

Comment: @oleksandrigo то есть в конце функции достаточно добавить оператор return?

Comment: @Karlail, не, тогда у вас на первом `return` будет выход из функции. Нужно переделать функцию для сборка данных в строку и ее вернуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переделать функцию для сборка данных в строку и ее вернуть

Пример:

```py
def repetition() -> str:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect (username, password, HOST+":"+PORT+"/"+SERVICE_NAME)

    print('Connecting!')
    cursor = conn.cursor() 

    sql = q1

    cursor.execute(sql) 
    alldata = cursor.fetchall()
    
    lines = []
    for i in alldata:
        lines.append(str(i[0]))
    cursor.close() 
    conn.close()

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

В одну строку:

```
    lines = [str(i[0]) for i in alldata]
```

Без списка:

```
    return '\n'.join(str(i[0]) for i in alldata)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это решение помогло! Я еще новичок в этом)

Comment: @Karlail, пожалуйста :)